# Free unused RAM in Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a Java class that allocates all files within a directory (6GB). Then for each file, does some text processing. When I check the ram usage, I can see that when I finish from a file and start to the next file, RAM does not get rid of the previous file - bad garbage collection, I guess. Is there a way to programatically free the finished file and its data?

```
public void fromDirectory(String path) {

        File folder = new File(path);
        disFile = path + "/dis.txt";
        if (folder.isDirectory()) {
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                File file = listOfFiles[i];
                if (file.isFile() && file.getName().contains("log")) {
                    System.out.println("The file will be processed is: "
                            + file.getPath());
                    forEachFile(file.getPath());
                    //Runtime.getRuntime().exec("purge");
                    //System.gc();

                } else
                    System.out.println("The file " + file.getName()
                            + " doesn't contain log");
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("The path: " + path + " is not a directory");
        }

}

private void forEachFile(String filePath) {
    File in = new File(filePath);
    File out = new File(disFile);

    try {
        out.createNewFile();
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(out.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(in));

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            if (line.toLowerCase().contains("keyword")) {
                bw.write(line);
                bw.newLine();
                numberOfLines++;
            }
        }
        reader.close();
        bw.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you did reset *all*  pointers and references to a file after it is closed?

Comment: Can't you process the file one by one? Did all heavy objects go out of scope? Maybe you're keeping them in a list and not getting rid of the list? Also: make sure to use the new [try-with-resources](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/java-7-try-with-resources-explained.html).

Comment: @Sirko Please tell me How?

Comment: @Dariusz I have about 300 file within about 10 dirs!

Comment: @EurikaIam Check your code for variables referencing the file and its contents. Then after closing the file, make sure all are reset to null or do not longer live in the current scope.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis What do you mean by proper behaviour? I don't need any data between the files! do I? once I finish one file, it has no need to be in RAM.

Comment: @EurikaIam: There's no need for it to be in RAM, but it doesn't hurt either. Your code and the expectation the memory is freed at once when you don't need it any more both look C-ish. Garbage is collected when the VM needs more memory. Calling `System.gc()` will in practice in most cases lead to worse performance and won't benefit memory consumption at all.

Comment: As others have suggested, the increased allocation by the JVM doesn't necessarily correspond to increased memory use or failure to GC. If the allocation is a problem, the best resolution might be just to reduce the maximum heap size of the JVM (via the -Xmx switch)

Answer (score 0):

You can strongly suggests the VM to do a garbage collection by calling `System.gc()` . It is generally considered a code-smell to do so.

Comment: System.gc() doesn't force garbage colleciton, does it? It only "strongly suggests" the JVM to do it.

Comment: @user570500 as you can see in the updated question, I already tried it with no difference at all!

Comment: @Eurikalam Ah sorry, I did not see your update in time. You can use visualvm to check whether the garbage collection is taking place and not freeing memory, or whether it is just not taking place at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistaking two things here: JVMs memory allocation and realy memory usage within allocated space.

JVM may allocate a lot of memory and **not free** it even after the objects that were using it were garbaged internally. It may be freed after some time or not freed at all.

You could try to reduce the memory footprint of your application, for example by not using toLowerCase, since it creates a new object. Maybe a precompiled regex search would be faster?

Using `System.gc()` as you did it, in your case, in my opinion, is acceptable. Whether it helps anything - I don't know.

As long as you have a lot of memory available and Java doesn't slow down because of too not being able to allocate more, I would leave it as it is. The code looks fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont have the available RAM, in most cases, which leaves the RAM to be full and then I can see the swapping between HD and RAM which makes slow. System.gc() did nothing good in this case.

Comment: @Eurikalam this is very strange; the `line` variables should be freed very efficiently and quickly. What JVM version are you using? What is the platform?

Comment: java version "1.7.0_13"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_13-b20)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

Mac OSX V 10.8.3

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are right about checking the memory from some profiler and deducing "correctly" that the file remains in memory why do you think it should be released immediately?

The JVM will garbage collect when the memory is running out (depending on the JVM configuration) not when developers think it should.

Also judging from your question I doubt if you used a profiler or a similar tool gauge JVM memory usage. Instead it's more likely you checked the memory being used by the JVM as a whole.

Also you shouldn't worry about these things unless you are encountering out of memory errors.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, the garbage collector runs when there is no more memory available. If you have `10` files of `100MB` each, and you set your heap to `4GB`, then chances are that you simply won't ever get any GC.

Now, for the "free the finished file and its data" part, you cannot really do this by yourself, and should not try to do so.

- If you want your application to be memory-efficient, then you can just set the maximum heap size to a small value.
- On the other hand, if you want your application to be really fast, then you don't want to suffer from any GC, therefore eliminating every `System.gc()` call and giving your heap as much memory as possible.

Trying to free memory yourself mean giving too much memory to your heap (your app is not memory-efficient) and triggering GC yourself (your app is not time-efficient either).

Note that in some cases, the JVM can give back memory to the OS. For instance, with G1, it will, but with CMS, it won't. See [this article](http://www.stefankrause.net/wp/?p=14) for more details.

Finally, if you use Java7, you should wrap your `InputStream`/`OutputStream` in a try-with-resources. Or, at least, wrap the `.close()` in a finally block.

Hope that helps !